# Nhibernate Where Condition

Tags: nhibernate

I want to generate a where condition in nHibernate Like Below Can any one Help me out

Select Id,Name from 
Employee 
where (id=@id or Id is Null)
i want the code to generate the where condition.

Answer (score 5):

You should check out the documentation here: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-narrowing

A solution using the criteria API is:

```
session.CreateCriteria<Employee>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", id) | Restrictions.IsNull(id));
```